# Youtube Data api V3, Getting video dimension

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am working on [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started). And I am looking for a way where I cn fetch all videos from particular channelId along with its video details like height,width and duration.

Now after searching for api docs I found [search api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search) to which provides the data from channel id. But the problem is , it only gives the content part. e.g. It provides very few details.

I found other ways which is provided in gdata api and youtube api v2 which is deprecated and I do not want to use them as they are deprecated.

Anyone has any idea, or better way where I can get list of video from channel id along with video detail(height,width,duration) in a single api hit.

Right now I am using URL something like this

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=<SomeChannelId>&maxResults=50&order=date&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```